# How do I use ListView with an accordion panel from the ajax toolkit?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

This one is kind of hard to explain. But basically, I'm trying to nest accordions using a ListView with a datasource. The problem is, that it won't allow listview into the accordion template. here's the layout:

```
>>Section (accordion pane)
   >>List of Documents to be reviewed
      >>List of Reviewing parties
```

The section is an accordion pane inside an accordion control. Inside of this is another accordion control which is built from a list of document currently in review. In other words, each document is another pane. The content of each of of the document panes is just an unordered list of reviewers (names).

So I need to be able to basically build the layout based on lists inside the object. I thought I would be able to do something like this:

```
<ajaxToolkit:Accordion runat="server" ID="accordionMain" HeaderCssClass="panelHeader" ContentCssClass="panelContent" CssClass="accordionPanel" FadeTransitions="True">
        <Panes>
            <ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane runat="server" ID="pane3" HeaderCssClass="panelHeader">
                <Header>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl="../icon_expand.gif"/>
                    Awaiting Reviewers 
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAwaitingReviewers" Text="(4)"></asp:Label>
                </Header>
                <Content>
                    <ajaxToolkit:Accordion runat="server">
                        <Panes>
                            <asp:ListView runat="server">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane runat="server">
                                        <Header>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblReviewItem"/>
                                        </Header>
                                        <Content>
                                            <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvReviewers" ItemPlaceholderID="phReviewers">
                                                <LayoutTemplate>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phReviewers"/>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </LayoutTemplate>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkMocReviewItem">
                                                            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfMocReviewItemId"/>
                                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblReviewItemAssignee"/>
                                                        </asp:LinkButton>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:ListView>
                                        </Content>
                                    </ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:ListView>
                        </Panes>
                    </ajaxToolkit:Accordion>
                </Content>
            </ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>
        </Panes>
    </ajaxToolkit:Accordion>
```

But the accordion isn't playing nice with the list view. I tried to use the listview to act as a template to add panes as required, but the accordion control won't allow anything but panes inside of the pane section.

Is there a way around this?

Here is a photo of the effect that I'm going for:
[image]

Comment: Try using Accordions in another Accordion, since Accordions are simply lists with headers and content.

Comment: @huadianz, that's exactly what i'm trying to do here. What I'm saying is that the accordions are generated from items in a list, and the content is generated from a list within each item in that list. To do this, I'm using a listview, which the accordion does not allow

Comment: What I meant was that instead of using a ListView, to generate a parent Accordion control with each sub-Accordion within the content fields of the parent Accordion, omitting the ListView altogether.

Comment: @huadianz, so then how will the accordion know what items to place in the content field?

Comment: The code-behind can populate the accordion control using any generic Iterator on the List that you are planning to bind the ListView with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the accordion control has a DataSource complete with a content template. If you bind it to something, then it will create panes for each item. I then placed a listview in the content template and all was good.